# apache rewrite http to https for non local connections

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, nginx

i try redirect all requests from non localhost connection from http to https.

i use [this combination](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-varnish-cache-4-0-with-ssl-termination-on-ubuntu-14-04)  https-> nginx -> varnish -> apache2 and want redirect direct connections to apache without ssl

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

this not work

Update 1

i put this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

and this is work - url in browser is redirected to https:// 
but i have unlimited loops, so apache redirect to https:// nginx as apache for http and it redirect. How to fix it?

UPDATE 2

if i change line

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=localhost
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
```

redirection stop work

UPDATE 3 
This not work because i have

http -> varnish -> apache 
or 
https -> nginx -> varnish -> apache

so for apache all time have 127.0.0.1
so i need know this is varnish request direct from http or from varnish

maybe add in nginx some var (header ?) and if request don't have this header in apache htacces redirect to https. What is best way to do this ?

UPDATE 4
i setup i nginx -

```
add_header Mea-request nginx;
```

and

in apache

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Mea-request} != ^nginx$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but still this not work

i think this line is not correct

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Mea-request} != ^nginx$
```

Answer (score 0):

working version :

in nginx

```
proxy_set_header X-APP_MEAREFER nginx;
```

in varnish

```
set resp.http.X-APP_MEAREFER = req.http.X-APP_MEAREFER;
```

in apache2

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-APP_MEAREFER} !^nginx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In anyone know better way please info.